# How to avoid conflicts about calling non existing elements in my custom JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, null, return, var

Let's say I have a file `mylib.js` in which I declared some functions to re-use on several projects I am working on.

```
var mylib = function(s) {
    var x;

    var obj = {

        myLibrary(s){
            if (x) return x;
            return document.querySelector(s);
        },

        hide(){
            x.style.display='none';
            return this;
        },

        show(a=''){
            x.style.display=a;
            return this;
        }

    };

    x = obj.myLibrary(s);
    return obj;
};
```

Now if I have another file `website.js` in which I am using my custom JS library. For example some of my pages contain sections which should stay hidden on startup so I gave them the class `.hidden` and applied this to my `website.js` file:

```
mylib('.hidden').hide();
```

... it works fine as long as there are any elements with the `.hidden`-class but on some of the pages where this file is also included there wouldn't be such classes so this is actually resulting in conflict and the console is telling me: `x is null`

What exactly is the reason for this conflict? How could I avoid such conflict?

Answer (score 0):

try `if(mylib('.hidden').length)mylib('.hidden').hide();`
hopefully I understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nullcheck the functions if x is null.

```js
var mylib = function(s) {
    var x;

    var obj = {

        myLibrary(s){
            if (x) return x;
            return document.querySelector(s);
        },

        hide(){
            if(x) {
              x.style.display='none';
            }
            return this;
        },

        show(a=''){
            if(x) {
              x.style.display=a;
            }
            return this;
        }

    };

    x = obj.myLibrary(s);
    return obj;
};

mylib('.hidden').hide();
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```